# How to group various groups in python into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which I want to group by the age.
So, here is the first part of the dataset:
[image]

It is a simulation for a inventory data. Größe means the number of people with the age (Alter) 15. Risiko gives every person a number and Geschlecht is feminine or masculine.

I want to add a column "Group" and give every people, which have the age 15-19 one number, than with age 20-24 one number and so on.
How can I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added data as text, not a picture, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
In [488]: import numpy as np

In [489]: conds = [df['Alter'].between(15,19), df['Alter'].between(20,24), df['Alter'].between(24,28)]

In [490]: choices = [1,2,3]

In [493]: df['Group'] = np.select(conds, choices)

In [494]: df
Out[494]: 
   Größe  Risiko Geschlecht  Alter  Group
0     95       1          F     15      1
1     95       2          F     15      1
2     95       3          M     15      1
3     95       4          F     15      1
4     95       5          M     15      1
5     95       6          M     15      1
6     95       7          M     15      1
7     95       8          F     15      1
8     95       9          M     15      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map and lambda to create a new column like so :

```
def return_age_from_range(age):
    # Max value in range is excluded, so remember to add +1 to the range you want
    if age in range(15, 20):
       return 1
    elif age in range(20, 25):
       return 2
    # and so on...

df['group'] = df.alter.map(lambda x: return_age_from_range(x))
```

Comment: thank you, but is there also a way to make it flexible? So maybe, in two days I want to group not in a step of 5, but in a step of 10...I want something like indices, which I can flexible use...for example j = 5 and then range(i,i+j) and so on?